# Is there any way to hide parameters from a url and show the modified url in the browser?

Tags: php, url

Suppose I have an url www.example.com/test/?code=nksdfnsdnfsdn&state=ksfsjafnjsfnjlnfd, now i want to hide the code and state parameters from the url and show www.example.com/test/

Is there any way to do this in php?

Comment: [this answer is easily found here](https://google.com)

Comment: I tried and when i can't find i posted here.

Answer (score 0):

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

will give you variables called $code and $state.

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/test");
die();
```

will redirect the user to the page without a query string

Comment: by forwarding them on in my example, I think the only other way is to POST them to the /test page instead of using a GET request.

Comment: That's the problem brother i can't use POST here. I have to use GET and do this :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending params using a form then you can use `input type="hidden"` for that

```
<input type="hidden" name="code" value="nksdfnsdnfsdn"?>"

<input type="hidden" name="state" value="ksfsjafnjsfnjlnfd"?>"
```

Or if you just want to remove params and want url without params then you can use `exploade` and can get the url without params

```
<?php
$url = "www.example.com/test/?code=nksdfnsdnfsdn&state=ksfsjafnjsfnjlnfd";
echo explode('?', $url)[0];
?>
```

Hope this will help you (y).

Comment: Thanks brother, Yesterday i tried this but when i try to rebuild the url with http_build_query there's no way to use the array $url)[0].